# Where do we report yields in a research report?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm in an integrated laboratory course at university that combines all the disciplines of chemistry that we have here. I was instructed to place the yield in the methods section of the report by my professor, but found that to be odd.

Is reporting the yield in the methods section a standard protocol in some paper formats?

Answer (score 4):

Your professor is right! Giving the yield in the method section, that is, together with detailed information on synthesis, workup and characterization of the products obtained, is standard in scientific journal I know or I have published in.